# packs url equivalent for asset_url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm upgrading a Rails 5 app to Rails 6, so in Rails 5 before webpacker was the default, I had a js file that I was loading separately from the application.js like this:

In **config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(magic.js)
```

and in my views I was using it like this:

```
<%= asset_url('magic.js'); %>
```

Now as Rails 6 uses webpack, I am adding the magic.js file to app/javascript/packs (which makes it as an entry file) and will produce a separate magic.js output in plus of the application.js, however I can't find any helper to access the URL, i.e: packs_url (equivalent to asset_url)

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using webpacker. So, You can use `javascript_pack_tag` to render javascript pack files.

Here is an example:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'magic' %>
```

For getting the url:

```
<%= asset_pack_path 'magic.js' %>
```

For more information visit docs:

https://github.com/rails/webpacker#usage

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/webpacker/Webpacker%2FHelper:asset_pack_path

Comment: Thanks Ravi, but I wasn't looking for outputing the javascript tag, I was just looking for getting the url, see my answer below

Comment: @medBouzid answer edited. Please check. Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I just found that it's possible to use `asset_pack_path` or `asset_pack_url` referring to this source:

github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/webpacker/helper.rb

Hope this helps someone in the future.

**Update**

as stated in the comment by KarimTarek, the url above has moved to https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/webpacker/helper.rb

Comment: They moved things around, those methods can be found here -> https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/webpacker/helper.rb

Comment: @KarimTarek thank you for pointing this out, I moved since from webpacker to use my own webpack_native gem and I'm no longer having headache with webpacker, I updated the post with the new url though. Thanks